# Using Case statement in Where clause in SQL developer

Tags: switch-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I am trying to write a "case" statement inside a "where clause" which has an "in" statement in the "then" part. Basically, the following code is what I want, but it's not the Oracle correct syntax. Does anybody have any idea what the correct syntax should be like?

```
       create or replace  PROCEDURE "Test"
       (
        Type in number
       )
       as
       begin
       select Id, Name, AccCode from myTable
       where case Type  
                 when 0 then AccCode in (130,131)
                 when 1 then AccCode in (230,231);
       end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want a `case` statement.  You probably just want

```
where (accCode in (130,131) and type = 1)
   or (accCode in (230,231) and type = 0)
```

If you really want to use a `case` statement, you could say

```
where (case when accCode in (130,131) then 1 
            when accCode in (230,231) then 0
            else null
         end) = type
```

But that will not be as readable nor will it be as easy for the optimizer to find a good execution plan.